# Fedora 24 (64bit) Git install (perl-devel, ParseXs install)

Tags: linux, git, perl, installation, fedora

Server OS is Fedora 24. 64bit.

I want to install Git 2.6.6.

So download source code and installed.

This server is offline. So i don't use 'yum'.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/git-2.6.6
make prefix=/usr/local/git-2.6.6 all
```

this is error message.

```
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (you may need to install the ExtUtils::MakeMaker module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Makefile.PL line 3.
```

So I install ExUtils::MakeMaker.

First I download rpm file(https://fedora.pkgs.org/24/fedora-x86_64/perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10-4.fc24.noarch.rpm.html)

And install rpm file

```
[root@swcm 다운로드]# rpm -ivh perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10-4.fc24.noarch.rpm 
오류: Failed dependencies:
    perl(ExtUtils::Install) >= 1.52 is needed by perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10-4.fc24.noarch
    perl(ExtUtils::Installed) is needed by perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10-4.fc24.noarch
    perl(ExtUtils::Packlist) is needed by perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10-4.fc24.noarch
    perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS is needed by perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10-4.fc24.noarch

[root@swcm 다운로드]# rpm -ivh perl-ExtUtils-Install-1.54-3.noarch.rpm
경고: perl-ExtUtils-Install-1.54-3.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 4026433f: NOKEY
오류: Failed dependencies:
    perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker) is needed by perl-ExtUtils-Install-1:1.54-3.noarch
    perl(VMS::Filespec) is needed by perl-ExtUtils-Install-1:1.54-3.noarch
```

perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker need to  perl-ExtUtils-Install.

perl-ExtUtils-Install need to perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker.

I don't know. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do you realise that Fedora 24 support ended last week? You are now using an unsupported operating system. I recommend upgrading to Fedora 25 or 26 as soon as possible.

Secondly, the version of `git` that is available for Fedora 24 is 2.7.4. You can download the RPM for this version from [here](https://fedora.pkgs.org/24/fedora-x86_64/git-2.7.4-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm.html). If you specifically need an older version, then perhaps you could explain why you think that (it's rarely true in my experience).

Thirdly, I think you're running up against [Fedora's deliberately broken Perl installation](https://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/). What you really want to do is to install the [perl-core RPM](https://fedora.pkgs.org/26/fedora-x86_64/perl-core-5.24.1-390.fc26.x86_64.rpm.html) (but that has dozens of dependencies that you will need to download).

To solve your current circular dependency problem, try installing both RPMs at the same time.

```
$ sudp rpm -ivh perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-*.rpm perl-ExtUtils-Install-*.rpm
```

But your life is going to get a lot easier if you can connect this machine to the internet - even temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

you can try carton.

- write a cpanfile
- carton install on one server with internet
- carton bundle
- then scp those .tar.gz or whatever to the server do not have internet
- carton install --cached (or cpanm the .tar.gz directly)
- once done, move those files under local to the system dir.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton

---

another way is that you can install all those modules with the server has internet (same OS), then scp or rsync the installed files)

Thanks